# What Application type of Google Oauth when developing React-Native app

Tags: react-native, google-oauth

I'm working on React-Native app and my application should be working on both IOS and Android Platform. I need to add feature of signing through Google.  So which application type should I choose on create client id page?

[image]

Comment: You have to create client id's or both android and ios, if you want app to work on both platforms